# Problem trying to construct JPA query from SQL

Tags: sql, jpa, join, predicate

I have a query which works fine in SQL but I can't seem to create the equivalent in JPA. The CriteriaBuilder "or" doesn't appear to execute an "or".

**These are the tables ...**

```
Table A

id : Long : primary key
b_id : Long : foreign key to id of Table B
c_id : Long : foreign key to id of Table C

Table B

id: Long : primary key
loc_id: Long 

Table C

id: Long : primary key
d_id : Long : foreign key to id of Table D

Table D

id: Long : primary key
loc_id: Long
```

**This is the data in the tables (in order of the fields listed) ...**

```
Table A:
1,  1,  null
2,  2,  null
3,  null,   1

Table B:
1,  5
2,  6

Table C:
1,  1

Table D:
1,  5
```

**And my sql query finds all the records in table A where the loc_id is 5 in Table B or Table D via the foreign keys. (2 results - row id 1 and row id 3)**

```
select * from A 
LEFT JOIN B on B.id = a.b_id
LEFT JOIN C on C.id = a.c_id
LEFT JOIN D on D.id = c.d_id
WHERE B.loc_id = 5 or D.loc_id = 5
```

**However I am struggling to code in JPA the same results.
I have tried below which creates 2 predicates which both find 1 record when executed individually but when I "or" them it produces 0 records. How can that be right?**

```
EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery cq = cb.createQuery();
Root<A> rt = cq.from(A.class);
List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

Join<B, A> join1 = rt.join("b_id", JoinType.INNER);
Join<C, A> join2 = rt.join("c_id", JoinType.INNER);
Join<D, C> join3 = join2.join("d_id", JoinType.INNER);
predicates.add(cb.or(cb.equal(join1.get("loc_id"), 5), cb.equal(join3.get("loc_id"), 5)));

CriteriaQuery x = cq.select(rt).where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
Query q = em.createQuery(x);
List<A> = q.getResultList();
```

**All suggestions gratefully accepted, thanks ....**

Comment: Don't you need `JoinType.LEFT`?

Comment: Yes - that has fixed it - thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution

```
EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<A> cq = cb.createQuery(A.class);
Root<A> rt = cq.from(A.class);

Join<B, A> joinB = rt.join("b_id", JoinType.LEFT);
Join<C, A> joinC = rt.join("c_id", JoinType.LEFT);
Join<D, C> joinD = joinC.join("d_id", JoinType.LEFT);

Predicate bPredicate = cb.equal(joinB.get("loc_id"), 5);
Predicate dPredicate = cb.equal(joinD.get("loc_id"), 5);

Predicate predicate = cb.or(bPredicate, dPredicate);

CriteriaQuery<A> x = cq.select(rt).where(predicate);
TypedQuery<A> q = em.createQuery(x);

List<A> result = q.getResultList();
```

Comment: @r.l. I have edited solution to your problem. All problems were caused by nullable b and c fields

Comment: Yes the JoinType.LEFT was the issue as sp00m pointed out. I'm not sure why the previous version that you had written without the Joins didn't work, but the version with the Joins does, so issue fixed, thanks. (I have removed my comments above as the solution is no longer the one they refer to)

Comment: @r.l.Previous version did not work because it use cross join by b_id and c_id. But if any of them is null then row is excluded from result